# handle Link_to_remote in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

How handle link_to_remote in rails4

```
= link_to_remote("Remove ", :url => {:controller => 'task', :action => "remov"},
:confirm => "Remove Force Result Notes \nAre you sure you want to remove Force Result Notes from selected task allocation(s)?", :method => :post, :with => "'selected_ta=' + $$('.select_box:checked').map(function(e) { return e.value; }).join()",
:after => 'Waiting.saving();', :complete => 'Waiting.hide();',
:failure => "alert('faill!!!')",
:html => {:title => "Remove Notes"})
```

I am confused to handle with,after,and complete. i have also read a lot of article but not found helpful .

Comment: Refer this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#link-to

Comment: @sebin in this article i have not found to handle with => JavaScript expression specifying the parameters for the XMLHttpRequest. Any expressions should return a valid URL query string.

Comment: I hope you have gone through this [link](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper/link_to_remote)

Answer (score 0):

If you want any logic to be executed or rendered it should be in controller, you could use [flash messages](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/action_controller_overview.html) for those purpose.